# Error installing GCC on Fedora

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, fedora, yum

I've been trying to install GCC on [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) 18. Here is a direct excerpt from my terminal window:

```
ishan@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.i686 0:4.7.2-8.fc18 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.7.2-8.fc18 for package: gcc-4.7.2-8.fc18.i686
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 for package: gcc-4.7.2-8.fc18.i686
--> Processing Dependency: cloog-ppl >= 0.15 for package: gcc-4.7.2-8.fc18.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libmpc.so.2 for package: gcc-4.7.2-8.fc18.i686
---> Package gcc-c++.i686 0:4.7.2-8.fc18 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++-devel = 4.7.2-8.fc18 for package:     gcc-c++-4.7.2-8.fc18.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cloog-ppl.i686 0:0.15.11-4.fc18.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libppl_c.so.4 for package: cloog-ppl-0.15.11-4.fc18.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libppl.so.9 for package: cloog-ppl-0.15.11-4.fc18.1.i686
---> Package cpp.i686 0:4.7.2-8.fc18 will be installed
---> Package glibc-devel.i686 0:2.16-30.fc18 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.16-30.fc18 for package: glibc-devel-2.16-30.fc18.i686
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.16-30.fc18 for package: glibc-devel-2.16-30.fc18.i686
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers for package: glibc-devel-2.16-30.fc18.i686
---> Package libmpc.i686 0:0.9-3.fc18.2 will be installed
---> Package libstdc++-devel.i686 0:4.7.2-8.fc18 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.16-24.fc18 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.16-24.fc18 for package: glibc-common-2.16-24.fc18.i686
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.16-30.fc18 will be an update
---> Package glibc-headers.i686 0:2.16-30.fc18 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 for package: glibc-headers-2.16-30.fc18.i686
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers for package: glibc-headers-2.16-30.fc18.i686
---> Package ppl.i686 0:0.11.2-10.fc18 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpwl.so.5 for package: ppl-0.11.2-10.fc18.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-common.i686 0:2.16-24.fc18 will be updated
---> Package glibc-common.i686 0:2.16-30.fc18 will be an update
---> Package kernel-headers.i686 0:3.8.7-201.fc18 will be installed
---> Package ppl-pwl.i686 0:0.11.2-10.fc18 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package               Arch       Version                   Repository     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 gcc                   i686       4.7.2-8.fc18              fedora         12 M
 gcc-c++               i686       4.7.2-8.fc18              fedora        5.5 M
Installing for dependencies:
 cloog-ppl             i686       0.15.11-4.fc18.1          fedora         96 k
 cpp                   i686       4.7.2-8.fc18              fedora        4.4 M
 glibc-devel           i686       2.16-30.fc18              updates       997 k
 glibc-headers         i686       2.16-30.fc18              updates       636 k
 kernel-headers        i686       3.8.7-201.fc18            updates       826 k
 libmpc                i686       0.9-3.fc18.2              fedora         51 k
 libstdc++-devel       i686       4.7.2-8.fc18              fedora        1.4 M
 ppl                   i686       0.11.2-10.fc18            fedora        1.5 M
 ppl-pwl               i686       0.11.2-10.fc18            fedora         37 k
Updating for dependencies:
 glibc                 i686       2.16-30.fc18              updates       4.2 M
 glibc-common          i686       2.16-30.fc18              updates        11 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  2 Packages (+9 Dependent packages)
Upgrade             ( 2 Dependent packages)

Total size: 43 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running Transaction Check
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib/audit from install of glibc-2.16-30.fc18.i686 conflicts with file from package audit-2.2.1-2.fc18.i686

Error Summary
-------------

[ishan@localhost ~]$
```

I don't know *why* this is happening. When I had yum-ed development tools, everything had installed properly, **other than the compiler**.

Is there a way to get rid of this error and install GCC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to update the package `audit` first.

```
yum update audit
```

Comment: And if that does not work, perhaps remove the `audit` package and install again `gcc` ....

Comment: How do I remove audit? is it dangerous to do so? (linux newbie here!)

Comment: @Ishan Have you tried updating it first? If that didn't work, you could try to uninstall it with `yum remove audit`, but chances are it might be a dependency and it won't let you. Try them both (in the order I said), and tell us what happens.

Comment: Done! updating audit did help!. @timss: I am happy you tried to help, but I finished it SECONDS before you posted!

Comment: Something fishy is going on here, if there is a newer `audit` package, the `yum install` should have picked it up as part of the transaction.